# Not sure how to work on with my array of bytes

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a big array of bytes. The first 2/3 of it is just blank basically,  just 0's. And at the really end there is some text that is useful for me and also a lot of jibberish in between that text.

Now how do you even filter out atleast the empty part from the byte array?

Right now, this is what I am doing:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;     
fis = new FileInputStream("resources/xampp2.zip");              
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);                
String decoded = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

It is a corrupted .zip, so the 2/3 as I sayd, is completely empty, and the rest is the Central directory. But right now It will just load it all into one really big String variable which is not really an efficient way of doing thing I belive?

But how would it be smart to iterate over blocks of bytes in my array, and filter out rubbish?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend converting a big array of binary data into a `String`.  `String`s are for text.  You'll end up corrupting your data if you do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove empty bytes from decoded String

```
decoded = decoded.replaceAll("\u0000+", "");
```

Comment: Well, this got rid of the big emptyness at the start of the file which is a big start! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to keep only text in your String you can use the same approach but replacing all non-word non-space chars http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html